# Using Linq foreach how to call a function with two arguments

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, .net-3.5

The following is my scenario. I need to invoke a using `List.Foreach(addressof fn)`. But it seems we need to pass the object as type of list and that function `fn(Type of List as Arg)`. Can we have another param ?.

Employee class

```
Class Employee
public  string Name
public  String DisplayName
End Class
```

--

```
Dim lstEmployee As New List(Of Employee)
Sub Main()
LoadEmployee()
PrintNames()
Update(5)
End Sub

Shared Sub PrintNames()
names.ForEach(AddressOf Print)     ' This will be working fine. 
End Sub

Shared Sub Update(Byval int as integer)
names.ForEach(AddressOf UpdateEmpName) ' Not possible
End Sub

Shared Sub LoadNames()
lstEmployee.Add(new Employee with{.Name="Bruce"})
lstEmployee.Add(new Employee with{.Name="Alfred"})
lstEmployee.Add(new Employee with{.Name="Tim"})
lstEmployee.Add(new Employee with{.Name="Richard"})
End Sub 

Shared Sub Print(ByVal s As Employee)
Console.WriteLine(s.Name)
End Sub 

Shared Sub UpdateEmpName(ByVal s As Employee. ByVal i as integer)
s.DisplayName= "EIN" +i+"-"+s.Name
End Sub
```

Is that possible ? . I am using .net 3.5

Comment: If all what you want is calling functions, why not relying on a normal for each? LINQ can only deal with "elements" of the given type/class. If "names" is a List of "Class1" and "Class1" contains the given functions, you can use LINQ to perform certain ordering on account of the outputs of these functions, for example. But you cannot bring subs into the picture (what information would they be providing to the query?). LINQ is not about doing many things iteratively (for this you have the loops) but for ordering a list of elements on account of different rules.

Comment: Put the `List(Of Employee)` in a class(`Employees`) and make the subs part of that class  `Employees.Print()`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible, but as this is untested code give it a try:

```
Shared Sub Update(Byval int as integer)
    names.ForEach(Sub(emp)
        UpdateEmpName(emp, int) 'param int from method update
    End Sub)
End Sub
```

I cannot see where `names` is declared so assume you have taken care of it else where?